# How to check whether a continuous signal is periodic or not?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, periodic

How to check if a continuous signal is Periodic or not?

My notes says
$\cos(\frac{3}{2}\pi t)$ is periodic because $T=4/3$.

And $\cos(\frac{3}{2}t)$ is not periodic as $T=4\pi/3$.

Comment: Both of those are straight lines, not periodic.  Did you mean to put the t inside the parentheses?   If so, then they are both periodic.  Where did you get these notes?  (Actually, `Cos(3π/2)t` is 0 everywhere, which could be considered "periodic" in a degenerate sense.)

Comment: @endolith: I have just edited the question assuming that $t$ is inside the argument of the cosine. I hope that was the intended form.

Comment: Yes t is inside parentheses

Comment: But then they're both sinusoids, which are always periodic.  Something is missing from your notes.

Comment: @endolith: Maybe he's confused with discrete-time sinusoids, which are only periodic if their periods are rational. His last example has an irrational period.

Comment: My note says period must be a fraction and between 0 and infinity

Comment: But $\pi$ is 22/7

Comment: $\pi$ is an irrational number says Wikipedia. I assumed it as 22/7 which is rational

Comment: @JasonR has likely hit it spot on.  both $x(t)=\cos\left(\frac{3}{2} \pi t \right)$ and $y(t)=\cos\left(\frac{3}{2} t \right)$ are perfectly periodic with their respective periods.  but the discrete-time sequences $x[n]=\cos\left(\frac{3}{2} \pi n \right)$ and $y[n]=\cos\left(\frac{3}{2} n \right)$ are different in the sense that $x[n+4]=x[n] \ \forall n$ yet there is no integer $N$ so that $y[n+N]=y[n] \ \forall n$.

Comment: and @DDR, i cannot believe that you thought that $\pi=\frac{22}{7}$.  all of those legislators from Indiana from around the turn of the previous century are now dead.  are you a reincarnation of one of them?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The Indiana legislature (actually a subcommittee) was considering a bill that would have _legislated_ the value of $\pi$ as $3$, not $\frac{22}{7}$.